# Getting the latest entry for a user from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

I am having a table named `names` in which there is a column named `name`. The users will enter a text before proceeding to next page.

In the next page I want to show them the data they entered on previous page.

In controller I tried something like `@names = current_user.names.all`

In views I did

```
<ul class="names-list">
    <% @names.each do |nname| %>

        <li>
          <%= link_to nname.name, edit_name_path(nname) %>
        </li>

    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

and show the last list item for the latest date. But surely there will a Rails shortcut to fetch the last data for the user. Any help?

UPDATED : Now I did something like 
`@last_name = current_user.names.last` in controller and in view 
`<%= @last_name.to_s %>` and it is generates `#<Name:0x007fae23ee1b68>` 
instead of name string.

Comment: You say your users are entering text. Where is that getting entered? I see a link, but I don't see any form of text input.

Comment: Can you post the view code for the previous page?

Comment: I already did that form part in the `index` action and its getting saved successfully to the **name** column in **nickname** table. The doubt here is how to query the last **name** for the user in rails controller?

Comment: `<%= form_for @name do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'input-field' %><br/>
<%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'signup-btn full-width' %>
<% end %>`

@Lanny @Stewart

Comment: Ok. Can you show the controller action that received that form input? Also, can you edit your post above? Code is easier to read there than in comments. Thanks!

Comment: `@name = current_user.names.build(nn_create_param)
    if @name.save
      flash[:success]= 'Name created'
      redirect_to share_path
end`

@lanny Thanks fr ur interest

Comment: So you should be able to `.order()` your @names based on `:created_at`.

Comment: Yes. I can. So how can i use `.order` to sort the last entry.

Comment: Now i did something like this `@last_name = current_user.names.last` in controller and in view `<%= @last_name.to_s %> and it is generates `#<Name:0x007fae23ee1b68>` instead of name string. @Lanny @Stewart

Comment: Yep, you're turning a Name into a string. Is there some attribute you want to display?

Comment: No. Just the name like **Peter** . But it is showing `#<Name:0x007fae23ee1b68>` which i don't want @Lanny

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92803/discussion-between-lanny-bose-and-praveen-kj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `<%= @last_name.to_s %>` only outputs the object `@last_name`'s name in memory, since thats specifically what you're asking it to output.

If your names table contains the column "name", 
the correct code in your view should be `<%= @last_name.name %>`
This specifically outputs the object @last_name's name, and not the objects name itself (in memory).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out via @Lanny

In controller

`@last_name = current_user.names.last`

In view

`<%= @names.name %>`